# How do I assign parameter to get predicted target value per sklearn regression model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using python and sklear. The df below is a DataFrame which has columns of 'age','width','height', 'price'. 
The column 'price' is the target value.

```
X = df[['age','width','height']]
y = df['price']

train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=9)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(train_X, train_y)
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(train_X)
score = model.score(test_X, test_y)
```

Now, if I want to get the prediction value with above model, with the parameter of age is 10, width is 120 and height is 250, how should I assign the input_value to get predicted 'price'?

```
input_data = ??????

pred_y = model.predict(input_data)
```

Comment: Try `model.predict([[10, 120, 250]])`?

Comment: it works but I need to use assigned value like input_data above. If I use a=10   b= 120   c = 250 and then   model.predict([[a,b,c]]) does NOT work, showing error code:   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: I just checked and it does work. Can you post what `print([[a,b,c]])` returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input_data = [[10, 120, 250]]`

This should work

Comment: Consider adding a description of what your answer does. If you do it will not only help not only OP but also others.